# org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed exception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I'm using Tomcat server, I started it yesterday morning and it continuously runs until this morning, but when I tried to login in my application it shows:

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
```

What is the problem - is any persistent session here or is sessionfactory null?

Comment: Post the **full** stacktrace please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem , 
ie i attached a different jar named c3p0-0.9.1.jar file and add some lines in hibernate-cfg.xml file

The code is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>                         
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<your db name></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>

           //Here is the extra code for handling the above problem.....

    **<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">1000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>**
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```